# Prompt to reload an externally modified file in Textmate 2?

Tags: textmate, textmate2

Im finding myself using TextMate 2 more and more for development these days

One thing that is bugging me is that it does not seem to reload a file when it is changed externally.

This is a big problem since I use terminal to switch git branches a lot, and it often results in accidentally saving an older version over the new branch

Sadly the TM team seem to have disabled the Issue tracker on github, and documentation just seems scattered far and wide over the web in tiny scraps.

Any ideas?

Comment: Be aware that there are bugs around Dropbox-synced folders... If your files/repository is stored there, maybe that's the reason they are not reloading automatically?

Comment: No all my git repos are hosted on vmware ESXI server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now it reloads the file silently whenever the file on Disk is changed. There is currently no option for a prompt.

Regarding the closed issue tracker: As an alternative, you can always send a mail to the Textmate users list if you find a problem.

Comment: thanks, Ill do some more testing as Im not sure the autoreload is working for me. Are there any issues with the files being hosted remotely (over afp) ?

Comment: after more testing it looks to be some form of fstat caching (either due to AFP or maybe even OSX). I can change a file externally and TextMate will not reload it, but as soon as I 'ls -l' the file from Terminal, TM can see that its changed, and autoreloads like you say

Comment: Just a (belated) followup to my question.....  I was suffering from lots of problems all centered around textmate and Samba (files reverting to older versions, TM not detecting changes, and even TM opening the wrong files using Quick Open).  Since upgrading to OSX Sierra all these problems have disappeared. It seems it was due to OSX samba client, being somehow outdated or not fully compatible with the samba server on my CentOS virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated to TM 2. In the past, I have enjoyed using TM to view development.log as I am introducing new or modified code. TM 1 would ask me if I want to revert to what's on disk and of course I would respond with Yes. Then I could see any additions to the log file. Occasionally I would empty the log file with Cmd+A, Delete, Cmd+S. Macromates, please make TM 2 work like TM 1 reloading content.

Answer (score 0):

I also could not find a solution to this problem which is still there, however it is possible to file an issue using this contact page: http://macromates.com/support

Additionally there are hidden setting which cannot be set from the GUI. Unfortunately they don't include and setting for automatic load from disk: https://github.com/textmate/textmate/wiki/Hidden-Settings